XDocument.Parse() weird behavior when double encoded string vs single encoded string
I have the following code,
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><DynamicFormExport elem=\"--&#32;Counts&#32;active&#32;dynamic&#32;forms&#13;&#10;SELECT&#13;&#10;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;COUNT(*)&#13;&#10;FROM&#13;&#10;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;DFForm&#13;&#10;WHERE&#13;&#10;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;FormActiveFlag&#32;=&#32;1&#13;&#10;\"></DynamicFormExport>");
        Console.WriteLine(doc);
                var doc2 = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><DynamicFormExport elem=\"--&amp;#32;Counts&amp;#32;active&amp;#32;dynamic&amp;#32;forms&amp;#13;&amp;#10;SELECT&amp;#13;&amp;#10;&amp;#32;&amp;#32;&amp;#32;&amp;#32;COUNT(*)&amp;#13;&amp;#10;FROM&amp;#13;&amp;#10;&amp;#32;&amp;#32;&amp;#32;&amp;#32;DFForm&amp;#13;&amp;#10;WHERE&amp;#13;&amp;#10;&amp;#32;&amp;#32;&amp;#32;&amp;#32;FormActiveFlag&amp;#32;=&amp;#32;1&amp;#13;&amp;#10;\"></DynamicFormExport>");
        Console.WriteLine(doc2);
    }
}

I aim to encode elem with the SQL query just once and export the same XML with the encoded query.
However, I noticed that single encoded XML attributes loose all the encoding when parserd through Xdocument.Parse().
What should I do to preserve the single encoded attribute?
